# How to automate makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have the following makefile. It works fine. The only problem is that it compiles all source files
in the source folder. I want to modify it in a way that it would detect and compile only the relevant source files (maybe detect them through the header?). I want to work with it in a way that if I have a new project, I would only have to add/change target name.

It is important to note that some project are depend on other. For example, 'scheduler' depends on 'task's' source files and 'task' depends on 'uid'.

Thanks.

```
CC = gcc

UTILS = test utils
TARGET = stack bit_array dvector linked_list queue cbuffer dlist sorted_list uid priority_queue task scheduler fsa vsa
MAIN_TARGET = vsa
EX = linked_list_exercise
TARGET_O = $(addsuffix .o,$(TARGET))

STD = -ansi
CFLAGS = -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra

INCLUDE_DIR = ./include/
SRC_DIR = ./src/
TEST_DIR = ./test/

DEBUG_DIR = ./bin/debug/
RELEASE_DIR = ./bin/release/

DEBUG = -g
RELEASE = -DNDEBUG -O3
VLG = valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes
GDB = cgdb



##~~~~~DEBUG~~~~##

all: $(TARGET)

target: $(MAIN_TARGET)    
    
$(DEBUG_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c
    @ echo $^ file compiling...
    @ $(CC) -I $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) -c $^ -o $@
    
$(DEBUG_DIR)%_test.o: $(TEST_DIR)%_test.c
    @ echo "\n"$^ file compiling...
    @ $(CC) -I $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) -c $^ -o $@

$(DEBUG_DIR)%.out: $(addprefix $(DEBUG_DIR),$(TARGET_O) %_test.o)
    @ echo $@ file linkering...
    @ $(CC) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) $^ -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(addprefix $(DEBUG_DIR),%.o %_test.o %.out)

%: $(DEBUG_DIR)%.out
    @ echo "/n~~~~~~~~~~"  $@_test  "~~~~~~~~~~"
    @ $^
    @ echo "~~~~~~~~~~"  $@_test done "~~~~~~~~~~\n"
    
vlg-%: $(DEBUG_DIR)%.out
    @ echo "~~~~~~~~~~"$@_test" VLG:~~~~~~~~~~"
    @ $(VLG) $^

gdb-%: $(DEBUG_DIR)%.out
    @ $(GDB) $^

## for main taget ##
vlg: $(DEBUG_DIR)$(MAIN_TARGET).out
    @ echo "~~~~~~~~~~"$@_test" VLG:~~~~~~~~~~"
    @ $(VLG) $^

gdb: $(DEBUG_DIR)$(MAIN_TARGET).out
    @ $(GDB) $^

clean:
    @ touch $(DEBUG_DIR)tmp.o $(DEBUG_DIR)tmp.out
    @ rm $(DEBUG_DIR)*.o $(DEBUG_DIR)*.out
    @ echo all .o and .out files in $(DEBUG_DIR) removed!

##~~~~~RELEASE~~~~##

release: $(addsuffix -release,$(TARGET))

target-release: $(MAIN_TARGET)-release

$(RELEASE_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c
    @ echo $^ file compiling...
    @ $(CC) -I $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) $(RELEASE) -c $^ -o $@
    
$(RELEASE_DIR)%_test.o: $(TEST_DIR)%_test.c
    @ echo $^ file compiling...
    @ $(CC) -I $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) $(RELEASE) -c $^ -o $@

$(RELEASE_DIR)%.out:  $(addprefix $(RELEASE_DIR),$(TARGET_O) %_test.o)
    @ echo $@ file linkering...
    @ $(CC) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) $(RELEASE) $^ -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(addprefix $(RELEASE_DIR),%.o %_test.o %.out)

%-release: $(RELEASE_DIR)%.out
    @ echo "~~~~~~~~~~"$@_test" RELEASE OUTPUT~~~~~~~~~~"
    @ $^
    @ echo "~~~~~~~~~~"$@_test" Exit~~~~~~~~~~\n"

clean-release: 
    @ touch $(RELEASE_DIR)tmp.o $(RELEASE_DIR)tmp.out
    @ rm $(RELEASE_DIR)*.o $(RELEASE_DIR)*.out
    @ echo all .o and .out files in $(RELEASE_DIR) removed!

clean-all: clean clean-release
```

Comment: _The only problem is that it compiles all source files in the source folder. I want to modify it in a way that it would detect and compile only the relevant source files (maybe detect them through the header?)._ Perhaps a far more practical and easier solution is to organize your source into sub-directories?

Comment: *detect and compile only the relevant source files (maybe detect them through the header?).* - you will have to define it properly. The answer would depend upon  what you consider "relevant files". Why are there "irrelevant" files in the same source directory?

Comment: Unrelated: `--ansi` is the same as `-std=c90`. A lot of good and useful features has been added to C since C90. Are you sure you want to limit yourself to that old version?

Comment: @yano I must keep them in the same folder since it is my class demand.

Comment: @EugeneSh. there are some other project's files in the same directory. They must remain there since it is our class setup.

Comment: Dunno then. I'm far from a `make` expert especially these days, but sounds like you need to specify which sources go with which targets then rather than wildcarding everything in the directory. Maybe create a source file naming scheme where each target's sources begin with a specific name, then wildcard from then on? It sounds like you want `make` to auto-discover which source files go with which target, which sounds like a chicken-and-egg paradox to me. Source files include header files, not vice versa. I don't see how anything could determine source files based on headers.

Comment: Besides, `make` doesn't do a blind rebuild every time, it's smart enough to determine which files were changed since last build and only build the necessary components to incorporate those changes (as long as all your dependencies are set up correctly). How is that behavior not good enough for what you're asking to do?

Comment: A few generic comments -- first, change your match-anything rule (`% : $(DEBUG_DIR)%.out` ...) to be a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) (`$(TARGET) : % : $(DEBUG_DIR)/%.out`), and add a [PHONY rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html): `.PHONY: $(TARGET)`.   Second it's cleaner to not include trailing slashes in makefile directory names, but instead add the slashes manually after each expansion that requires it.   Also, for your clean do an `rm -f ...` to prevent errors if you don't have any .o files.

Comment: When you say it builds everything, are you doing `make`, or `make targname`?   If you only want to build `stack`, for example, you would do `make stack`, which should not build everything else.   If you just do `make`, it will build the first target `all`, which is dependent on `$(TARGET)`, so it will build everything in `$(TARGET)` that happens to be out of date.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry it builds everything eve when I am doing make stack. any reason why?

Comment: First remove the `@` prefixes from your compile lines so you can see the command that make actually invokes.  I personally think they're a bad idea but if you really want them at least make them optional; see for example https://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/  Second, run `make -d` and make will tell you (rather verbosely) why it decides to rebuild any given target.

Comment: You do not have any explicit rule for `stack`. The only pattern rule that matches `stack` is `%: $(DEBUG_DIR)%.out`, so make uses this one and tries to first build `./bin/debug/stack.out`. The only rule that applies is `$(DEBUG_DIR)%.out: $(addprefix $(DEBUG_DIR),$(TARGET_O) %_test.o)` that has all `./bin/debug/xxx.o` as prerequisites where `xxx` is any of `stack bit_array dvector linked_list queue cbuffer dlist sorted_list uid priority_queue task scheduler fsa vsa`, plus `stack_test`. So, you get what you asked for: all these object files are built.

Comment: If `./bin/debug/xxx.out` depends only on `./bin/debug/xxx.o` and `./bin/debug/xxx_test.o` you should rewrite your `$(DEBUG_DIR)%.out: ...` rule as `$(DEBUG_DIR)%.out: $(addprefix $(DEBUG_DIR),%.o %_test.o)`. If you do so `make stack` should need only `./bin/debug/stack.o` and `./bin/debug/stack_test.o`, none of the others should be built.